# simple appengine go datastore query returns no result

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to the go appengine datastore API and I'm having difficulties with my first datastore query.

I cannot retrieve any entry, even if I remove all my filtering code.

I've tried to create a simple test snippet that demonstrates the issue :

```
package mypackage

import (
    "appengine/aetest"
    "appengine/datastore"
    "testing"
)

type Toto struct {
    Name string
}


func TestGetAll(t *testing.T) {
    c, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    // insert a test object
    _, _ = datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "entitykind", nil), &Toto{"totoname"})
    // fetch all objects
    var result []Toto
    datastore.NewQuery("entitykind").GetAll(c, &result)
    if len(result) != 1 {
        t.Fatalf("wrong length of result :%v", result)
    }
}
```

If I pause the program after the insertion and check the admin server, I see that the entity is properly inserted.

I cannot understand why my query fails to retrieve it.

I also tried to initialize my `result` slice to a length of 1, but the `Name` property is not overwritten by `GetAll`.

Comment: You don't see _immediately_ the inserted entity because the AppEngine SDK simulates the **eventual consistency** that applies to the High Replication Datastore.

Comment: Also note that you can force strong consistency and thus you will see your inserted entity immediately if you create a context like this: `c, err := aetest.NewContext(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})`